# Tableau CRM: How to add dynamic "date" via computeExpression?

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics, saql

in my dataflow I have a *computeExpression* that should add a "Date" field.
That date field should always contain the first of the current month (e.g. for right now: Feb. 1st 2021).

I've tried to do it like this:

```
toDate(toString(now(), "yyyy-MM") + "-01")
```

My idea was to take the current date, get it as a String without the day (e.g. "2021-02") and convert it into a date again with a fixed day-string of "01".

However this results in a strange error message when I run the data flow:

> Something went wrong while executing the Month + 1 node: Only the dataflow owner or users with the View All Data permission can download the log

Note: Month + 1 is the label for my computeExpression.

If I simplify my SAQL expression to, say:

```
now()
```

It works just fine: I get the current date: *2021-02-03*.

My question now: How can I get the first of the month in that date field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I've found the solution.

For anyone else stumbling upon this:

You **need** to add a time component to the expression.
It's not explicitly documented but with that it works, so I've came up with that expression:

```
toDate(toString(now(), "yyyy-MM") + "-01 00:00:00")
```

Setting my date field to midnight.